# AG grid react focus issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

In AG grid react.. press tab to move next cell that time focus and editing enable on each cell I moved using tab but if I sorted grid ascending and decending after that if i click one cell editing and focusing enable on someother row.what is the solution for that?

I wrote function for oncellfocused and tired

Comment: Can you explain this issue with minimal reproduction in stackblitz and share the link here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.